# Петрушка и - Петрушка

Tags: этимология

Мне всегда было интересно: какая связь между названием огородного растения петрушка, русской народной куклой и, собственно, именем Петр?
Заранее благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, интересно получается: однокоренные слова-то, родственные
Имя Пётр (стар. Петр) происходит от древнегреческого «пет-ра» - камень, скала, утес, каменная глыба. В свою очередь перевод на греческий язык арамейского (древнееврейского) имени-слова Кифа (камень, скала) дал имя Петр, имеющее то же значение: камень, скала. Произношение с «ё» - только в русском языке.

И растение - petros "камень" + selinon "сельдерей", в польском превратившееся в петрушку.

А кукла Петрушка - тот же Пётр - Пётр Петрович Уксусов (по другой версии Петр Иванович) – таково было полное имя Петрушки. Свыше 400 лет назад о нем впервые написал, путешествуя по России, немецкий дипломат и писатель Адам Олеарий – в своих записках «Камедь о Петрушке». По другой версии Петрушка до середины 19-ого века не имел своего имени и часто его называли «Иван Рататуй» или «Иван Ратютю», что свидетельствует о французских корнях этой куклы. И действительно, Петрушка - остряк в красном кафтане и красном колпаке вовсе не такой исконно русский персонаж, как считалось ранее. У Петрушки есть свои братья и старшие родственники. Так, в Венгрии – это витязь Ласло. Он колотит всех не палкой, как Петрушка, а сковородой. Во Франции старший «брат» Петрушки – Полишинель, в Англии – Панча, в Италии – Пульчинелла, в Турции – Карагёз и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

"Петрушка" (растение) заимствовано из польского языка, в котором pietruszka (через посредство нем. яз.) усвоено из лат. petroselinum < греч. petroselinon "горный сельдерей", сложения слов petros "камень" и selinon "сельдерей".

Этимология названия куклы доподлинно неизвестна, думаю это произошло под влиянием схожего персонажа французской кукольной комедии "Полишинеля". Во всяком случае внешность у куклы далеко не славянская. Впервые кукла упоминается в воспоминаниях Олеария (XVII век).

А имя Пётр известно на Руси со времён крещения. Свое распространение имяИ получило в связи с деятельностью апостола Симона Зеведеева, которого Иисус Христос нарек Кифой или в греческом варианте — *Петра*. Дословно это означает *камень, скала*.

Answer (score 1):

Имя Пётр греческого происхождения и по-видимому пришло вместе с крещением Руси. Собственно от уменьшительной формы и произошло название куклы `Петрушка`. Образование славянский имён часто связывалось с некими признаками, видимо это как-то связывает имя и эту зелень. Однако не думаю что существует способ узнать подробнее, как появилась подобная связь.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что к имени Пётр петрушка отношения не имеет. Чисто внешнее сходство. Петрушка - это пряное растение. Что мы делаем, когда срываем листик петрушки? Мы растираем его пальцами и нюхаем: оцениваем насколько хорош запах. Никогда так не делали? Вот от этого действия и пошло: "потрушка" от тереть, растирать. Плюс приставка по- и словообразовательные суффиксы. Аналогичное действие мы проводим и с другими запашистыми растениями. Например мята. Почему "мята"? Потому что мы её мнём, чтобы четче ощутить запах.